# HasMany with JunctionTable findAllJoin not serializing junction table attributes

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I have a User model which is connected to projects via a junction table. This junction table has some additional attributes like allow_read which I want to pass back in my response.

```
request.user.getProjects({
    where : { do_sync : true, allow_read : true },
}).success(function(projects) {
    // send proper response
    response.jsonp(projects);
}).error(function(err) {
    // send error response
    response.status(500).jsonp(err);
});
```

In this code block 'allow_read' works properly and projects[0].user_project returns the additional attributes from the User_Project model. The problem is when 'projects' get serialized the user_project object disappears. projects[0].values also does not contain a user_project property even though projects[0].user_project does exist.

My question is if there is anyway for sequelize to automatically stringify both the projects and their junction table attributes without manually building that object myself?

Comment: Also although this is a simplified version of my code which shows the same issues I have tried setting the fields I want in both 'attributes' and 'joinTableAttributes'. The values in the joined table never serialize when converting to JSON unless I manually do so.

Comment: This is not possible at the moment, but you are welcome to provide at feature request for it